# why modern object oriented languages like Java, VB.NET and C# do not support multiple Inheritance

Tags: oop

A programmer can extend the functionality and re-usability of classes using Multiple Inheritance. If it is useful in C++ then why modern object oriented languages like Java, VB.NET and C# do not support multiple Inheritance. Justify your answer with solid reasons.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the early GUI frameworks designed for "fat client" applications, used multiple inheritance which lead to several issues down the line primarily with ambiguity and casting between the base types. One of the main problems is termed the Diamond which is discussed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance

Comment: will u please explain it in an easy or concise way ?

Comment: I'll try... When multiple inheritance is used in large systems , with multiple levels of multiple inheritance it become confusing as to which inherited methods of an object are actually being invoked  (how is that )

Comment: Thank u so much  newbie :)